# How do you show syntax highlighting in a displayed code snippet?

Tags: elm, highlight.js

I've found that highlight.js has syntax highlighting for displayed code snippets but I could not find documentation for how to use it in conjunction with elm.

What do I do in order highlight displayed code like an IDE does with elm via 3rd party code or built in?

Comment: Suggestion: Should this have `highlight.js` tag so that people following that tag would find this question?

Comment: added the highlight.js tag. I don't need to specifically use highlight.js but its something i'm trying to see if I can use.

Comment: I think this question might be a bit too broad. But I think your best bet is to use a web component. Any library that manipulates the dom is not going to work well with Elm's virtual dom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Elm package if the language you want to highlight is supported:

https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/pablohirafuji/elm-syntax-highlight/latest/

To use [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/), you can either create a [custom element](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements) or use it together with `elm-explorations/markdown`, see its [README](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-explorations/markdown/latest/#code-blocks).  For example https://ellie-app.com/7mbxTyMHXkqa1.